# Type casting date to string in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to cast a date type to string in JSP and its not happening

I have to re populate a form which stores a field with date type and submit it after re-edit.
The value to displayed in the form is in date format and while submitting after editting must be in string type for the controller to accept it.

View Code:

```
<td>
<input class="orderInput" type="text" 
       name="bdate${i}" id="bdate${i}" value="${employee.bdate}" />
</td>
```

Controller Code:

```
String txtdateOfBirth = request.getParameter("bdate" + i).toString();
```

Here `employee.bdate` is of type date so when submitted errors as `txtdateOfBirth` is of string. So can anyone tell how can I convert `employee.bdate` to string in JSP to solve my issue?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: you can try `${employee['bdate']}`

Comment: the error im getting is parse exception as the var textdateOfBirth in the controller is of string type and employee.bdate is of date type Remember getParameter("bdate" + i).toString() gets employee.bdate which is submitted as a form field and is assigned to txtdateOfBirth

Comment: @ user2064376 : have a look at my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

what ur date format in the form??

you can simply using constructor of date

```
// year month and date u can substring from the string u get and parse it to Integer
Date bDate = new Date(year,month,date);
```

Comment: I cant change the controller as it affects the other scenarios as Im just enhancing for some other scenarios. The only way I can keep things simpler is by casting the employee.bdate in the form to string before submitting it

Comment: may be you can try convert it in javascript function. add this function to your onsubmit="yourFunction()" in your form tag. Sorry if it not help.

Answer (score 0):

U cannot convert directly a date into string .u have to use a class

// Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting 
   // the string representation of date (month/day/year)
          DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Get the date today using Calendar object.
          Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
   // Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
  // representation of a date with the defined format.
           String reportDate = df.format(today);

// Print what date is today!
           System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<td>
   <c:set var="myDate">
      <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MMM/yy hh:mm a"   value="${employee.bdate}" />
   </c:set>

   <input class="orderInput" type="text" name="bdate${i}" id="bdate${i}" 
          value="<c:out value="${myDate}"></c:out>" />
</td>
```

First set your date in a variable `myDate` using `c:set` and use any format that is valid as per [the javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

And use that variable using `c:out`